# How to make bars have different colors in d3?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, bar-chart

Im trying to make my bars having different colors in d3. Tryed next code, but it didnt worked:

```js
var color = d3.scaleOrdinal([`#383867`, `#584c77`, `#33431e`, `#a36629`, `#92462f`, `#b63e36`, `#b74a70`, `#946943`]);
    
    
var rectGrp=svg.append("g")
    .attr('transform','translate('+padding.left+','+padding.top+')');
        
rectGrp.selectAll("rect").data(Data_CARD).enter()
    .append("rect")

    .attr("width",xScale.bandwidth())

    .attr("height", function(d){
        return chartArea.height-yScale(d.Amount);
    })

    .attr("x", function(d) {
        return xScale(d.Case);
    })

    .attr("y", function(d) {
        return yScale(d.Amount);
    })

    .attr("fill", function(d,i) {
        return color[i];
    });
```

Bars have the same color: black.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are doing

```
var color = d3.scaleOrdinal([`#383867`, `#584c77`, `#33431e`, `#a36629`, `#92462f`, `#b63e36`, `#b74a70`, `#946943`]);
```

`color` is a scale function.

So in your `fill` attr, you would do something like:

```
.attr("fill", function(d,i) {
    return color(i);
})
```

Also, you are seeing black because you are setting `fill` to an invalid property, probably `undefined`.

I couldn't test it, but I think it should do it.